# Searchable dropdown menu on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, xaml, search, dropdown

I need to create dropdown menu with search functionality. My goal is to allow user to easily pick from quite large list of predefined values. I found TextInputLayout with AutocompleteTextView as very nice and simple.

But I am missing 2 functions:
a) I don't want to allow user to fill custom value. He must pick from predefined values only. It can be done by adding `android:inputType="none"` to AutoCompleteTextView, but after that, search functionality is gone.
b) It would be nice to be able to search values containing users input, not only these that starts with it. Example: write "land" and get "Poland".

Is it possible to achieve this functionality with AutocompleteTextView? Or is there any simple alternative?

Thank you.

This is my implementation of AutocompleteTextView:

XAML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Country">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/actCountries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Fragment

```
val countries = arrayListOf<String>("Czech Republic","Slovakia", "Poland", "Germany","Austria")
val countriesAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries)
binding?.actCountries?.setAdapter(countriesAdapter )
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach can be using a `TextWatcher`. You can update the dropdown list inside the `onTextChanged` callback by using `.filter` extension on the `countries` list.